# OWLClassExpression concat

Tags: owl, owl-api

My goal is to do the same as string:

```
String x = "a";
x = x + "b";
result: "ab";
```

Is there a way to do the same with OWLClassExpression? Is there a method to use always the same instance to concatenate other OWLClassExpression?
If I do something like:

```
OWLClassExpression tmp = myOWLDataFactory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf();
tmp = myOWLDataFactory.getOWLObjectUnionOf();
```

Obviously, it overwrites and this is very bad for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you show, x appears on both sides of the = sign. You need to do the same in the OWL case:

```
OWLClassExpression tmp = myOWLDataFactory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(somevalues);
tmp = myOWLDataFactory.getOWLObjectUnionOf(tmp, someothervalues);
```